# Dealing with error : testng.selenium.endpoint must be a configured System property

Tags: testng

When using Maven archetype for **Testng** , the execution through pom.xml happens seamlessly but with Testng plugin the error comes :

> [MyArtifact] testng.selenium.endpoint must be a configured System
> property!

Answer (score 0):

I am answering in two parts : 1. Quick fix 2. Detailed resolution

**1. Quick fix**

- Identify the file testng-selenium.properties in your repo , it should be at the same level as your testng.xml.
  [image]
- Add the below line there , after replacing google.com with your application URL :

  testng.selenium.endpoint=https://google.com
- It will look something like this:
  [image]
- Execute it again

**2. Detailed resolution**

- Read the documentation at : https://jsdevel.github.io/java-testng-selenium/
- You will see that there are three ways to update the system property
- Identify the suitable way as per your project need and set the property